# Translating angular bootstrap directives using angular-translate without filters?

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate, angular-bootstrap

How do you best translate angular bootstrap directives like uib-tab and uib-tooltip without the use of filters?

Filters add a lot of watchers, so I don't want to make it like:

```
<uib-tab heading="{{'A. Manually add emails'|translate}}" is-open="true">
```

Is there anothe way to do it?

Comment: "Filters add a lot of watchers" where did you find out about this?

Comment: https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/wiki/Getting-Started

Comment: No watcher is created here, you are using a constant string

Answer (score 0):

Although all previous comments are correct, here's an alternative, if you really want to avoid the filter:

```
function TranslateAttr($translate) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: {
      pre: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        var attribute = attrs.translateAttr,
            attributeValue = attrs[attribute];

        if (attributeValue) {
          $translate(attributeValue).then(function (translation) {
            attrs.$set(attribute, translation[attributeValue]);
          });
        }
      }
    }
  };
}
```

Now to use it in your example:

```
<uib-tab heading="{{'A. Manually add emails'}}" is-open="true" translate-attr="heading">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **$translate** service with **instant** method inside your controller in order to get immediate explicit translation without any **$filter**, like this: **$translate.instant(your-key)**, returns string/object depends on your input, see: [$translate](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/api/pascalprecht.translate.$translate)

```
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $translate){
   ...
   $scope.translatedTooltip = $translate.instant('tooltip-key');
   ...
});

<uib-tab heading="{{translatedTooltip}}" is-open="true">
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use one time binding where you are sure that value wont change:

```
{{::name | translate}}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/NS6XFZGgflWsR9Zk9d5L?p=preview

But if you use filter for constant string - no watcher will be created.

Comment: this doesn't work because angular filters have higher priority and won't be translated after the directive creates the html.

Comment: you don't have angular bootstrap directives in that plunker. Please read the question title!

Comment: just checked - using bootstrap directives makes no difference